# How to prevent 'Bad Request' error while opening HTTP address on a Apache server with SSL (with non-default port)?

Tags: 14.04, apache2, ssl, redirect, https

as you may know if you configure apache2 with SSL (non-default port) and open it with 'HTTP' address you will get this error:

**https**://[ip-address]:20443 --> **http**://[ip-address]:20443

> **Bad Request**
>
> Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
>   Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
>   Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.

If you use default port for SSL (443) the best solution is to redirect **http** to **https** (for example with 'Rewrite')
But if you use non-default ports this method doesn't work. Because http://:20443 and https://:20443 are on same port and apache2 cann't listen a port twice!

So how can i redirect http://:20443 to https://:20443 automatically?

Comment: Since you are receiving a Bad request from the server, you may be able to create an error page that redirects to https. What is the exact status code you receive when calling the URL with HTTP?

Comment: based on access.log, it return 400 status code: "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400

Comment: In that case, I would argue that it is not possible as 400 is too generic and you can end up with infinite loop. Nginx has a cleaner solution for this as it defines a custom status code for this error, if you would be willing to use it instead of Apache https://ma.ttias.be/force-redirect-http-https-custom-port-nginx/

Comment: Thanks @Dan but i cannot switch to nginx. also i'll workaround on error page.